# Blackberry Phonegap/jQuery Mobile Select Menu

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, drop-down-menu

Hi i've developed an app in Phonegap and its working perfectly within an Android device.

I've swapped the phonegap.js to the Blackberry one and installed it on a device. Everything is working fine and looks great apart from the select menus im using arnt working.

Im using the example from jQuery just with different values and names. Any idea why its not dropping down a box? Many thanks. (This is when its just on a device, ive tried it in Ripple emu and it seems fine)

```
<label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1">
 <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
 <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
 <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
 <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 make sure you are also using jQuery Core 1.6.4, if you use jQuery Core 1.7+ with jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 or earlier you will get unexpected errors (especially with Blackberry).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set data-native-menu="false" and see if it works better:

```
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false">
 <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
 <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
 <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
 <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
</select>
```